# Transforming a chessboard into bitmask

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

I am trying to transform a matrix chessboard into an unsigned long long. If there is a coin in that pos I update the corresponding mask. Heres my code

```
    unsigned long long int mask = 0;
    cout<<mask<<endl;
    for(int i=0;i<8;++i)
        for(int j=0;j<8;++j){
            int pos = i*8+j;
            cin>>board[i][j];
            if(board[i][j] == 'P')
                mask|=(1<<pos);
    }
     for(int i=0;i<8;++i)
     {
        for(int j=0;j<8;++j)
        {
            int pos = i*8+j;
            if(mask&(1<<pos))
                cout<<1;
            else
                cout<<0;

        }
        cout<<endl;
     }
```

But when I give the following input

```
........
...P....
.....P..
...P....
........
........
P......P
.......P
```

the output is as follows

```
00000000
00010000
10000101
00010001
00000000
00010000
10000101
00010001
```

which is clearly wrong. But I don't seem to find any mistake here . thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use `unsigned long long` literals in the bit manipulation code:

```
            mask|=(1ull<<pos);
                    ^^^
```

and

```
        if(mask&(1ull<<pos))
                  ^^^
```

If your compiler doesn't support the `ull` suffix, you may have to explicitly cast the `1` to `unsigned long long`.

P.S. If you're wondering how your current code ends up producing the output it does, observe that the output consists of the two halves of the board ORed together and printed twice.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is twofold:

- you should not be using `unsigned long long`, to start with.
- constants default to `int`, you need to explicit cast them (or used typed and named ones)

Regarding `unsigned long long`: there is no guarantee that its width is sufficient, it could well be only 32 bits on old platforms/compilers. Therefore, you should: `#include <cstdint>` and then use `uint64_t`.

Regarding constants, you may either use `uint64_t(1)` in place, or simply define `static uint64_t const Bit = 1;` and then use `Bit` instead of `1` in your formulas.